# Android: Firebase token getting invalid length

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get Push noptification via Firebase. While trying to get token from firebase am getting the token length as 140 (Invalid), Some times getting valid token of length 150. Same device is am testing, So there is no device specific issue

**Invalid Token**

```
APA91bEQ14IejWxNnQ_pzY-GMs3Bx7Wi_0Iib7CKTNVlRGAFujP-VsWQwxBpMB4D1JUV91Ao_E6Ry8qEfJbjGLEEmyPX2oBI7KCmf4BIk5Jqyd456jxFvt2S-zIFyBFI2xwxOf5FwOEN
```

**Valid Token**

```
fzdOrLvN02w:APA91bETJie1o1v8LPWdJKvdI_XzqDdZ7z5FggXZASbD4pp9JLXMGeRudnyLEcY75u0ZVd494znghVJD7ZhZymN7g1bdE07qLocsoOOjlk9TwBa6kgGqHSSsKfENTM62UM_M_azwsvlU
```

The diffrence am notice that , there is a colon with 12 characters for a valid token. But I dont know what the reason

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Manifest**

```
   <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseRegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false"/>

    <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And am using **onHandleToken()** override function for getting the FCM token , that function is in **MyFirebaseRegistrationIntentService**

Can anyone please tell me why am getting the invalid token for some times.

Comment: There is no specified size by firebase for token check server side db length is there any limit ?

Comment: @Krutik  I raise ticket to the Firebase support team, and they confirm that the token length of 140 is invalid.

Comment: Could you add your code for getting the token(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get token in firebase using below code:

```
    String fcm_idtoken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Comment: In MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class....        @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

Comment: The token that geting form  MyFirebaseInstanceIDService and MyFirebaseRegistrationIntentService are same. So same issue will occur

Comment: am getting the token . But am facing the issue as invalid token length of 140. It mentioned in my question

Comment: Remove from menifest file this line:   <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseRegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false"/> and also remove android:exported="false" from both service class.

Comment: I tried that, but stil some time the length of the token getting as 140 (invalid).

Comment: @ Vishal Vaishnav by default the exported= false, so there is no effect for removing that line. Here Firebase Instanse id is missing. It something other reason

Comment: @ Vishal Vaishnav the issue is fixed, it not because of firebase version. if there is any content for GCM,Then Instance id will not get from fierbase

Comment: yupp thats very nice. Well which content do you use of GCM?

Comment: @Binil Surendran:-Is it sure that the issue was due to GCm

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get **Valid Token Id**

```
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                    Log.d(TAG,deviceToken);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,e.toString());

                }
            });
```